# How to repeat ajax call until a specific value is returned by the server?

Tags: ajax, angularjs

I need to populate a progressbar, I have a service giving me the current progress.
My idea would be something like:

```
$http.get('service').success(function(response, status, headers, config){
         $scope.progress = response.progress;
         $scope.progressL = response.progress+"%";
         if(response.progress < 100){
             //repeat
         }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just place the api call in a function, and let the handler call it:

```
function checkProgress(){
    $http.get('service').success(function(response, status, headers, config){
       $scope.progress = response.progress+"%";
       if(response.progress < 100){
           checkProgress();
       }
   }
}
```

Though, you'll probably want to cap it in some way. You might also want to add a timeout so that it waits a while between checks, something along the lines of `$timeout(checkProgress, 5000)`.

**EDIT for clarity**: The reason this won't overflow your stack is that Angular's promises `$q`, which the Promise returned by `$http.get('service')` is implemented by, will trigger asynchronously.

So In the following case:

```
$http.get('service').success(function(){ console.log('callback'); });
console.log('Returning');
return;
```

The console will say "Returning" before "callback" every time.

When the resolution is guaranteed to be async, you're fine. Here's a demo of resolving async thousands of times: http://jsfiddle.net/23Ldaj42/

Were this not the case (as in, if `$http` callbacks were not guaranteed to be called async), instead you'd want to protect yourself by forcing it to be async as follows:

```
function checkProgress(){
    $http.get('service').success(function(response, status, headers, config){
       $scope.progress = response.progress+"%";
       if(response.progress < 100){
           $timeout(checkProgress); // This will perform async
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: This is nice, but wouldn't it eventually fill the stack?

Comment: Nope, the outer function finishes and clears way before the callback ever triggers. Asynchronous stuff.

Comment: Added a section explaining why the stack will be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You could call this recursively:

`var callback = function(response, status, headers, config){
     $scope.progress = response.progress;
     $scope.progressL = response.progress+"%";
     if(response.progress < 100){
         $http.get('service').success(callback);
     }
};
$http.get('service').success(callback);`